# Does not work post-query when login

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to verify the user's password using bcrypt. But, unfortunately, my post-request does not work, it just loads for a long time and that's it.

I have a model user.js with this code:

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePasswords = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};
```

And i have a controller auth.js with this code:

```
export const signin = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { login, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ login });

    if (!user) {
        return next({
            status: 400,
            message: 'User not found'
        });
    }

    try {
        const result = await user.comparePasswords(password);
    } catch (e) {
        return next({
            status: 400,
            message: 'Bad Credentials'
        });
    }

    req.session.userId = user._id;
    req.json(user);
};
```

The handling of incorrect input works well and the server returns false messages for me, but does not process the correct input.

Comment: Do you mean to do `res.json(user)`?

Comment: What bcrypt library are you using?

Comment: This version bcrypt https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Comment: Ok, because the one called *bcrypt-nodejs* has a `bcrypt.compare()` function that doesn't return promises. I think Explosion Pills answered the question.